# Outlook 2010: is it possible to restrict search to a given period of time?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

I have disabled the windows search service because it was causing some lag on my work machine.
(Conflict was about the anti-virus, my compiler and the indexer that were blocking each-others, and the search service was the only one I could disable without too much harm)

The only side effect is that now my searchs on outlook are really slow. 
I have 2-3 years of mails and I just can't throw everything away.

The search options for Outlook are a bit empty.

I would like to specify a time range to boost search response time, because quite often I'm looking for mails received in the last 3 months. For the others I don't care to wait few minutes to do a full scan.

Do you know any way to achieve that ? 
Or, as a plan B, to re-enable the search service but only for mails ?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you trying to simply order your email in date order? or search for email received during a specific block of time?

Comment: Do you often search back to 2 or 3 years? If only on occaison, why not just create 2 archives (1 for 3 years ago and 1 for 2 years ago), at least this means when you do a normal search you'll only be looking through 1 year's worth of data.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams : I'm trying to search in a subset of mails to avoid a very long search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an advanced find or throw in a [search operator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-HA010238831.aspx) -

`received:>=1/1/2014 AND received:<=1/31/2014`

Comment: using the search operators is very slow too... for example it tooks several minutes to fetch: received:last week. Your example is even worst: I don't see any answer before 30 seconds.
The advanced find is blazing fast, but a bit cumbersome to use... but I'll use it now for my search!